# angularjs button event not firing when clicked

Tags: angularjs

I'm missing something here in the wiring. When the button is clicked the alert in the method isn't displayed.

```
  <div id="mapFilter" ng-controller="MapsController">
   <div>
     <h3>{{SelectedCustomer.officeName}}</h3>
     <input type="button" ng-click="getProperties()" value="Get Data" />
   </div>

   <div>
     <p>hotel count: {{allHotels.length}}</p>
     <p>preferred count: {{preferredHotels.length}}</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The expected execution point:

```
    $scope.getProperties =  function () {
    var msg = 'Unable to load Properties: ';

    alert("getProperties");
```

Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4eF1Wu4tURysTji0b5kO?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: Just couple of typos.. http://plnkr.co/edit/7o56S8?p=preview Marking for closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive to auto-bootstrap your application:

```
<body ng-app="main">
```

You will then get some errors in your plunker that you have to fix first (i.e. load ng-resource, ...)